# Error while editing ViewObject query in Expert mode

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using Oracle's BC4J framework, in that I get following error while editing ViewObject query in JDeveloper.

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when JDveloper IDE has problem doing a certain task, you can check the Error Details to know more about this problem, but usually if you Press Continue and continue working everything should be alright with you.